# Loop the user input until user enters a valid input

Tags: rust

I have a learned a little bit of rust and usually in my codes I like to implement a function that loops the user input until it is correct, but in this case it does not work, and I do not know why. I have tried with a method called `is_ok()` but this always returns false. The code is the following

```
use std::io;

macro_rules! input {() => {{
        let mut it = String::new();
        loop {
            io::stdin().read_line(&mut it).expect("Failed to read input");
            if (it.trim().parse::<i16>().is_ok()) {break}
            else {println!("Error: Different Type convertion");}
        }
        it.trim().parse().expect("please give me correct string number!")
}}}

fn main () {
    println!("Enter any number: ");
    let my_num: i16 = input!();
    println!("Entered number is {}", my_num);
    println!("Enter any other number: ");
    let mut a: i16 = input!();
    println!("Entered number is {}", a);
    a += my_num;
    println!("The sum of two numbers is {}", a);
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This code asks me to enter two numbers, prints their sum, and then terminates. I can run it just fine on my machine

Comment: Nitpick: Use functions, not macros. Especially if you just learned Rust.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Can reproduce. Type a letter, press enter and try to type a number the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`read_line()` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line) (emphasis mine):

> Locks this handle and reads a line of input, **appending it** to the specified buffer.

So if you entered something invalid, it'll stay there and the parsing will fail.

[`clear()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.clear) the string before calling `read_line()` or create a new string every time.